# How to implement pop-up notification in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, notifications, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to implement pop up notification in Xamarin.Android mvvmcross project, all my notifications are invoked through viewModels , I have a notification service that i inject as a dependency both in the PLC and the Droid project , i'd like to use the same notification service to invoke a pop up.

I want the pop up to be like a crouton (https://github.com/slown1/Xamarin.Crouton).

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [userdialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) which is a great plugin for popups!

If you want to use Crouton you probably need to create an interface for it which you implement independently for the different platforms. How to do that can be found in the [MvvmCross wiki](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control)